# Start playing a video at a certain time

Tags: linux, cron, ffmpeg, at

I want to play a video at a certain time. Like an alarm. for instance, at 07:00 play video.mp4

I have tried this with crontab and with `at`, but no success yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a little script for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$1" = "-q" ] && shift && quiet=true || quiet=false
hms=(${1//:/ })
printf -v now '%(%s)T' -1
printf -v tzoff '%(%z)T\n' $now
tzoff=$((0${tzoff:0:1}(3600*${tzoff:1:2}+60*${tzoff:3:2})))
slp=$(((86400+(now-now%86400)+10#$hms*3600+10#${hms[1]}*60+${hms[2]}-tzoff-now)%86400))
$quiet || printf 'Alarm goes off at %(%c)T.' $((now+slp))
sleep $slp
mplayer /path/to/video.mp4
```

Call it with the desired time like `alarm.bash 7`, `alarm.bash 7:1:3` or `alarm.bash 07:01:03`. You may use the `-q` option to disable the terminal output. Designed to serve as an alarm clock it's not possible to set a time more than 23:59:59 in the future with this script – I suggest to combine it with `cron` if necessary.

Comment: Works perfectly!